# can i gain more performance for insert operation by not including select columns in covering index?

Tags: database, indexing

Can i gain more performance for insert operation by not including select columns but just include where columns while defining covering index and at the same time by doing this preserve read performance in intense write tables?

By excluding select columns for covering index i am aiming to reach the actual value(select column) by only clustered index(primary key) in actual table.

For example;

```
FruitsForSale Table columns 
rowid |  fruit  |  state  |   price

SELECT price FROM fruitsforsale WHERE fruit='Orange' AND state='CA'

CREATE INDEX Idx ON FruitsForSale(fruit, state);
(instead of CREATE INDEX Idx ON FruitsForSale(fruit, state, price);)
```

Comment: I can't quite follow this - could you please add a small example of the table , the covering index, and the insert. Also, is there a specific RDBMS tag that can be added?

Comment: RDBMS will be important here - e.g. in SqlServer, you can implement covering indexes with the `INCLUDE()` keyword e.g. `CREATE INDEX Idx ON FruitsForSale(fruit, state) INCLUDE(price);` has benefit over your first index as it will allow you to use the covering index without the RID lookup back into the clustered index for Price, and has a slight storage benefit over your second index since price will only be stored on the leaf nodes of the covering index.

Answer (score 0):

The performance gain for the insert will be very small, probably not measurable at all - the index is a bit smaller so there are less bytes to write, while the number of write operations basically stays the same. On the other hand, the given select in your example will be noticeably slower, like taking twice the time, since the index is not enough to satisfy the query. For that reason, I don't think this is a good idea.